# How to decrement Model values using javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the two buttons to delete files in my application. First button wipes away the chosen file and second one wipes away all the user's files. Second button isn't seen when the count of user's files is less than 2. So, when the user delete file by clicking the first button, I should check is the count of attachments more than 1 and if it false - JS should remove second button.
So here's the question - How to decrement Model values using javascript?

Comment: For this, the simplest solution is: store `@Model.Attachment.Count` value in a javascript global variable (like `var attachCount = @Model.Attachment.Count` ) and while removing attachment, decrement this js variable value.

Comment: @mmushtaq
it seems to be working, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to store `@Model.Attachment.Count` value in a javascript global variable (like `var attachCount = @Model.Attachment.Count`).